# Const keyword with function signature

Tags: c++, function, stl, constants

Here is my simple code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class alloc { };

template <typename T, typename Alloc = alloc>
class vector
{
public:
    void swap(vector<T,Alloc> &v) { cout << "swap()" << endl; }
};


template <typename T, typename Alloc>
void swap(const vector<T,Alloc> &v1,const vector<T,Alloc> &v2)
{
    v1.swap(v2);
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> x;
    vector<int> y;

    swap(x,y);

    return 0;
}
```

The code snippet run without problem.But i can't get any outputs

Then I delete `const` keyword.

```
void swap(vector<T,Alloc> &v1,vector<T,Alloc> &v2)
```

I get output `swap()`

I have read "The reason is that const for the parameter only applies locally within the function, since it is working on a copy of the data. This means the function signature is really the same anyways."

So i thought there is no difference between write or not write const.if i insist to write const here,how do i modify the code to get the output `swap()`

Comment: Try to change your class name `vector` and function name `swap` to something else, they conflict with name of STL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an excellent illustration of why `using std` should be avoided.

In order to debug this problem, remove `using std`, and add `std::` in places where you want the behavior from the standard library. Fortunately, there is only one such place, i.e. the `swap` function in the template class:

```
void swap(vector<T,Alloc> &v) { std::cout << "swap()" << std::endl; }
```

Now try compiling again to [see the error](http://ideone.com/SLIeU5) preventing your `swap` with `const` from being used:

> prog.cpp:19:5: error: passing `const vector<int>` as `this` argument discards qualifiers

When your program was `using std` C++ had an alternative of picking [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) over your own `swap` function when your function was not applicable. That is exactly what it did, without any warning, because it assumed that it is what you want it to do.

The error also tells you what to do in order to make `const`-qualified vectors be accepted: add `const` to the parameters of `vector::swap`, like this:

```
void swap(const vector<T,Alloc> &v) const { std::cout << "swap()" << std::endl; }
```

Now your program compiles and runs again ([demo](http://ideone.com/ebFIH7)).